# Base-64 encoded form of the .pfx file

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, pfx

**How to get the base 64 encoded form of .pfx file?**

I am trying to implement one of the azure resource manager templates

```
"certData": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Base-64 encoded form of the .pfx file"
      }
    }
```

You can see the cert data wants that information.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use below powershell command to generate the Base-64 encoded string.

```
$fileContentBytes = get-content 'D:\brando.pfx' -Encoding Byte

[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes) | Out-File 'D:\pfx-bytes.txt'
```

It will convert the pfx to  Base-64 encoded string in a txt file.

Comment: i don't use windows OS ,can you suggest for linux or macOS

Comment: You could try to use base64 [OPTION]... [FILE]  to encode the pfx file. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64).

Comment: If you're using Powershell Core (Windows Terminal) then in the first command instead of "-Encoding Byte" param you should use "-AsByteStream".

Comment: It appears that -Encoding is no longer valid.  What would be the new command?

Answer (score 4):

For Powershell Core (6+) you need to use

```
$fileContentBytes = Get-Content 'path-to.pfx' -AsByteStream

[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes) | Out-File 'pfx-bytes.txt'
```